# Непонятная ошибка в class

Tags: php

Есть код под хамп работает а под Ubuntu нет, ремируешь QRcode::png  класс всё норм, но естественно картинок не создаёт, в чём может быть отличия. Разрешения в Ubuntu на папки поставил
xampp 7.1.15
ubuntu 7.1.26-1 в нём класс ханадрит
Ссылка на код где class лежит
https://pastebin.com/MwG5znG9

```
echo "<h1>PHP QR Code</h1><hr/>";

    //set it to writable location, a place for temp generated PNG files
    $PNG_TEMP_DIR = dirname(__FILE__).DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'temp'.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

    //html PNG location prefix
    $PNG_WEB_DIR = 'temp/';

    include "qrlib.php";    

    //ofcourse we need rights to create temp dir
    if (!file_exists($PNG_TEMP_DIR))
        mkdir($PNG_TEMP_DIR);


    $filename = $PNG_TEMP_DIR.'test.png';

    //processing form input
    //remember to sanitize user input in real-life solution !!!
    $errorCorrectionLevel = 'L';
    if (isset($_REQUEST['level']) && in_array($_REQUEST['level'], array('L','M','Q','H')))
        $errorCorrectionLevel = $_REQUEST['level'];    

    $matrixPointSize = 4;
    if (isset($_REQUEST['size']))
        $matrixPointSize = min(max((int)$_REQUEST['size'], 1), 10);


    if (isset($_REQUEST['data'])) { 

        //it's very important!
        if (trim($_REQUEST['data']) == '')
            die('data cannot be empty! <a href="?">back</a>');

        // user data
        $filename = $PNG_TEMP_DIR.'test'.md5($_REQUEST['data'].'|'.$errorCorrectionLevel.'|'.$matrixPointSize).'.png';
        QRcode::png($_REQUEST['data'], $filename, $errorCorrectionLevel, $matrixPointSize, 2);    

    } else {    

        //default data
        echo 'You can provide data in GET parameter: <a href="?data=like_that">like that</a><hr/>';    
        QRcode::png('PHP QR Code :)', $filename, $errorCorrectionLevel, $matrixPointSize, 2);    

    }    

    //display generated file
    echo '<img src="'.$PNG_WEB_DIR.basename($filename).'" /><hr/>';
```

> На то что ругается в логах дальше

```
    class QRimage {

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    public static function png($frame, $filename = false, $pixelPerPoint = 4, $outerFrame = 4,$saveandprint=FALSE) 
    {
        $image = self::image($frame, $pixelPerPoint, $outerFrame);

        if ($filename === false) {
            Header("Content-type: image/png");
            ImagePng($image);
        } else {
            if($saveandprint===TRUE){
                ImagePng($image, $filename);
                header("Content-type: image/png");
                ImagePng($image);
            }else{
                ImagePng($image, $filename);
            }
        }

        ImageDestroy($image);
    }

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    public static function jpg($frame, $filename = false, $pixelPerPoint = 8, $outerFrame = 4, $q = 85) 
    {
        $image = self::image($frame, $pixelPerPoint, $outerFrame);

        if ($filename === false) {
            Header("Content-type: image/jpeg");
            ImageJpeg($image, null, $q);
        } else {
            ImageJpeg($image, $filename, $q);            
        }

        ImageDestroy($image);
    }

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------
    private static function image($frame, $pixelPerPoint = 4, $outerFrame = 4) 
    {
        $h = count($frame);
        $w = strlen($frame[0]);

        $imgW = $w + 2*$outerFrame;
        $imgH = $h + 2*$outerFrame;

        $base_image =ImageCreate($imgW, $imgH);

        $col[0] = ImageColorAllocate($base_image,255,255,255);
        $col[1] = ImageColorAllocate($base_image,0,0,0);

        imagefill($base_image, 0, 0, $col[0]);

        for($y=0; $y<$h; $y++) {
            for($x=0; $x<$w; $x++) {
                if ($frame[$y][$x] == '1') {
                    ImageSetPixel($base_image,$x+$outerFrame,$y+$outerFrame,$col[1]); 
                }
            }
        }

        $target_image =ImageCreate($imgW * $pixelPerPoint, $imgH * $pixelPerPoint);
        ImageCopyResized($target_image, $base_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $imgW * $pixelPerPoint, $imgH * $pixelPerPoint, $imgW, $imgH);
        ImageDestroy($base_image);

        return $target_image;
    }
}
?>
```

авкп

```
[Fri Jul 05 13:04:46.832565 2019] [php7:error] [pid 18833] [client 10.59.3.1:1683] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function ImageCreate() in /*/*/*/qrimage.php:75\nStack trace:\n#0 /*/*/*/qrimage.php(33): QRimage::image(Array, 4, 2)\n#1 /*/*/*/qrencode.php(494): QRimage::png(Array, '/*/*/*/t...', 4, 2, false)\n#2 /*/*/*/qrencode.php(286): QRencode->encodePNG('PHP QR Code :)', '/*/*/*/t...', false)\n#3 /*/*/*/index.php(71): QRcode::png('PHP QR Code :)', '/*/*/*/t...', 'L', 4, 2)\n#4 {main}\n  thrown in /*/*/*/qrimage.php on line 75
```

Comment: Смотрите логи. Скорее всего не подключена графическая библиотечка

Comment: хз логи где смотреть, там просто сайт вываливается на ubuntu? и что за билиотека где для убунту ёё поставить?

Comment: /var/log/httpd/ или /var/log/apache2/

Comment: @Node_pro посмотри я добавил код на который в логах ругается

Comment: напишите еще сами "матюки"

Comment: На будущее (и сейчсас тоже). Когда описываете проблему с ошибками, обязательно пишите текст ошибки. Иначе по каким моментам понять, о чем речь?

Comment: @Node_pro посмотри вывел ниже  вроде на эти строчи  $base_image =ImageCreate($imgW, $imgH);
            
            $col[0] = ImageColorAllocate($base_image,255,255,255);

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106991/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-imagecreate

Comment: @Node_pro  вот это поставить? apt install php7.1-gd

Comment: @Node_pro  можеь оформить ответом + поставлю оказалась библ нет apt install php7.1-gd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если скрипт использует графические методы, нужно убедится в подключении графической библиотечки.
[Ссылка на stackoverflow(Eng) с этой же проблемой](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3106991/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-imagecreate)